# Why warnings appear on my Mac Terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos

Hello since I installed Rails on my MacOS and when I run commands on terminal, I keep getting warnings. What is this stuff?

```
→ rake db:migrate

/Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:209: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

/Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:209: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

Comment: It means that everyone has write access to your `/usr/local` directory, and this is generally bad. You can *probably* fix it with Disk Utility by selecting your boot drive and clicking "Repair Permissions".

Comment: Hi Zneak, That did not fix the issue. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo chmod -R o-w /usr/local
```

This removes the "Other" write permission on all sub directories of /usr/local.